# Gareth Emery's Soldier Lyrics Clarification

Tags: lyrics, electronic-music

So all the [lyrics sites](https://genius.com/Gareth-emery-soldier-lyrics) seem to say the 2<sup>nd</sup> verse of [Gareth Emery's Soldier](https://youtu.be/7b1WeyQ5cHw) as saying:

> When you're falling down and **you're on the fence**
>   I will be your shield I will keep you safe

However what it actually sounds like (and what would make more sense):

> When you're falling down and **your armor fails**
>   I will be your shield I will keep you safe

Is there a more official source that could clarify this for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess [Roxanne Emery's Facebook post on 22 April 2013](https://www.facebook.com/RoxanneEmeryMusic/posts/10151556398949939) can be considered as the most official source:

> When you're falling down, **and your armour fails**, I will be your shield, I will keep you safe. When you know you can't make it on your own... I will be your solider <3
>
> <sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

Comment: OK, follow up question, what's the correct spelling of armor/armour? JK... thanks for the great source!